# Items also occurs in a set

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

**The task**

> You're given strings J representing the types of stones that are
>   jewels, and S representing the stones you have.  Each character in S
>   is a type of stone you have.  You want to know how many of the stones
>   you have are also jewels.
>
> The letters in J are guaranteed distinct, and all characters in J and
>   S are letters. Letters are case sensitive, so "a" is considered a
>   different type of stone from "A".
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: J = "aA", S = "aAAbbbb" Output: 3
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: J = "z", S = "ZZ" Output: 0
>
> Note:
>
> S and J will consist of letters and have length at most 50. The
>   characters in J are distinct.

**My functional solution**

```
const findNumberOfJewels = (j,s) =>  [...s].reduce((num, x) => [...j].includes(x) ? num + 1 : num , 0);

console.log(findNumberOfJewels("aA", "aAAbbbb"));
```

**My imperative solution**

```
function findNumberOfJewels2(j,s) {
  let res = 0;
  const set = new Set(j);
  for (const x of s) {
    if (set.has(x)) { ++res; }
  }
  return res;
};

console.log(findNumberOfJewels2("aA", "aAAbbbb"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functional approach is almost certainly faster despite having worse big-O — \$O(j \cdot s)\$ functional vs \$O(j + s)\$ imperative — because linear searches of small arrays are [very fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031382/2570502).

You don't need to destructure `j` and adding a boolean to a number coerces the boolean to 0 or 1.

`sum` is a better name than `num` and `c` is a good name for a character iterator.

```
const findNumberOfJewels = (j,s) => [...s].reduce( (sum, c) => sum + j.includes(c),  0 );
```

Comment: +1 Be careful when making assumptions about JS performance.Running both OPs solutions over a wide range of inputs, the functional solution is from 25% -75% the speed `fastTime / slowTime` of the imperative.  Your modified version is a significant improvement over the OP's, under specific circumstances can be much faster then the imp version (also much slower ). But the alloc of `[...s]` and coercion of `j.includes` to `Number` means it will always be slower (by ~10%) than `findJ(j,s) {var r=0,i=s.length;while(i--){j.includes(s[i])&&r++}return r}` (Note that GC cost of `[...s]` is not timed)

Comment: Were you able to get those results within the given size constraints?  I couldn't find valid inputs that make the imperative version beat a linear search.  The whole string sits in L1 cache and I'm skeptical that it's possible for Set's lookup characteristics to repay its setup time.